# Arrangement of elements to avoid duplicate on consecutive positions

Tags: arrays

I have an array with `N` elements and I have `M` numbers. U need to arrange the M(1, 2, 3, ..M) numbers in array, the numbers in M are repeated. Such that constitutive elements in the array are not same.

Ex : `N=9` and `M=3` `[4, 4, 1]` means 1 appears 4 times in the array, '2' appears 4 times and 3 appears only one time.

So the possible arrangement will be `[1,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,2]`.

Ex : `N=8` and `M=2` `[3, 5]`.

There is no possibility to arrange the elements such that two consecutive elements are not same.

I need to find weather the **arrangement** is **possible or not**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (Java syntax):

```
int max = M[0];
int sum = M[0];
for ( i = 1 ; i < M.length ; i++ ) {
    if ( M[i] > max ) {
        max = M[i];
    }
    sum = sum + M[i];
}

if ( 2*max <= s+1 ) {
    System.out.println("possible");
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT possible");
}
```

**Time complexity**: O(|M|)

---

The idea is that if you want to place those numbers into an array, you'll start with the longest sequence, then you choose the first longest sequence in order to avoid repeating.

```
E.g.:
----------- arr: []
1, 1, 1, 1
2, 2
3
----------- arr: [1]
1, 1, 1
2, 2
3
----------- arr: [1, 2]
1, 1, 1
2
3
----------- arr: [1, 2, 1]
1, 1
2
3
----------- arr: [1, 2, 1, 2]
1, 1
3
----------- arr: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
1
3
----------- arr: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3]
1
----------- arr: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1]
```

So, if the maximum number from M is at most the sum of the others + 1, it's possible to obtain that array without repeats:

```
max <= sum_of_the_others + 1      | + max
```

which is equivalent to

```
max + max <= sum_of_all_numbers + 1
```

which is equivalent to

```
2*max <= sum_of_all_numbers + 1
```